# error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char’ c++ array

Tags: c++

Very new to C++ and when I compile I get this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char’
```

What on earth does this mean? I presume it's something memory related, I have not initiated the array or something along those lines?

Here is my code:

```
char students[150][150];
int main()
{
    readFile();
}

void readFile()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file("scores.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i  <  150; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 150; x++) {
            students[i][x] = getline(file, line, ' ');
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i  <  150; i++) {
        cout << students[i][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointing you to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline. That line is probably the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Silly mistake, appreciate your reply.

Comment: Do you want to make a vector of strings where every index is a file's line?

Comment: My file looks like this: EZQRGTSX TTFFTTTTTTTTT TFTTFT (student id | test answers (true/false) empty space means they never answered. I have 150 students. Would it be easier to use a vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getline returns a basic_istream, and you can't set it to the type char